# How can I reduce lag when loading background images in android studio?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, background, loading

I'm developing an Android game through android studio, but when I draw moving background images through Bitmap.decodeResource and drawBitmap, my game's FPS goes down to 10 which is unplayable. Is there an alternative way to draw slowly moving images in the background? I'd like the image quality to be reasonable still, but the background will just be a few pictures of some trees sliding across the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you didn't call `Bitmap.decodeResource` every time you render the scene. You have to call it just once - at the beginning, when you initialize all the other stuff:

`Bitmap gameBackground=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.game_background)`

Then, in the game loop, you can render the image with `canvas.drawBitmap(gameBackground)`. Of course at the end, after the scene loop, you have to free the allocated memory using `gameBackground.recycle()`.

Comment: I only call decodeResource once when I initialize the game panel, but it's still laggy when the picture resolution is greater than like 600x600. Is this supposed to happen? Do I have other options to show a moving background image?

Comment: You can try to put the image in the drawable-nodpi folder under /res directory. In this way your image won't be unnecessary resized which by default takes a lot of memory and CPU. Another thing - your image is better to be PNG.

Comment: I think resizing will be necessary for my application. Is there no easy way around this? Android studio isnt made to handle high quality images?